# Intellij IDEA syntax warnings, cannot resolve symbols

Tags: intellij-idea

I've one problem on Intellij IDEA.. There are everything working but, IDEA shows warnings like this.

Here are some screenshots: 
[image: screen1]

And when I compile it, it's working:

[image]

Please, who can tell me, where is a problem?

I **watched Duplicates** questions and can't find answer for it!

Comment: can you show us screenshots of the lines where IDEA shows errors

Comment: @ElSam There're not have errors, i find problem and fix it))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Fix this problem: just two steps

**`File --> Invalidate Chaches / restart`**

There is one warning: you clear your local history..

Idea say you:

> The caches will be invalidated and rebuilt on the next startup.
>
> WARNING: Local History will be also cleared.
>
> Would you like to continue?

Accept it and wait, after restarting, problem has been fixed.